# Angular CLI Webpack / Node proxy

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, angular-cli

I am migrating AngularJS and JSP application to Anuglar 2+.

I have setup a proxy to redirect pages which are not migrated to Angular 2+ to another host using proxy.conf.json.

```
{
    "/legacy": {
    "target": "https://localhost:8111",
      "secure": false,
      "changeOrigin": false,
      "logLevel": "debug"
    }
 }
```

If user tries to request /legacy/index.jsp then it renders file from 
https://localhost:8111/legacy/index.jsp - which works fine

Similarly, if user tries to request /legacy/api/data then it internally requests https://localhost:8111/legacy/api/data - which works fine.

How can I change the proxy to only redirect .jsp requests or only redirect for api calls?

Thanks!